# Can i use array with lambda notation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my Code :

```
string[] aa = new string[] { "Title", "Image", "Description" };
     for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
     {
       aa[i] = ems.SupportAdds.Where(x => x.ArticleId == id).Select(x => x.aa[i]).ToArray();
       ViewBag.Collection[i] = aa[i];
     }
```

I am getting error near `x.aa[i]`.It is saying Table doesn't contain `aa[i]`. I want to use like that to short code. Please help me. I have its long version too which is working with my code.

Here is that one:

```
 var Title = ems.SupportAdds.Where(x => x.ArticleId == id).Select(x => x.Title).ToArray();
 ViewBag.Collection1 = Title;
 var Description = ems.SupportAdds.Where(x => x.ArticleId == id).Select(x => x.Description).ToArray();
 ViewBag.Collection2 = Description;
 var Image = ems.SupportAdds.Where(x => x.ArticleId == id).Select(x => x.Image).ToArray();
          ViewBag.Collection3 = Image;

And In view :
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Collection2[i]
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Collection2[i]
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Collection3[i] // with increasing forloop which is working fine.
```

But I want to short it so I thought to use an array but it is not working with  array. Can you guys suggest me the better way to write this code with lambda notation? Help will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can improve performance by making changes like this

```
  var allRecords= ems.SupportAdds.Where(x => x.ArticleId == id);
  ViewBag.Collection1 = allRecords.Select(x => x.Title).ToArray();
  ViewBag.Collection2 = allRecords.Select(x => x.Description).ToArray();
  ViewBag.Collection3 = allRecords.Select(x => x.Image).ToArray();
```

Comment: Take care, that isn't very efficient

Comment: I know, Using Viewbag isn't a good way but I was having no option as I was unable to use ViewModel for that. Can you suggest any way to solve it in the better way? #Oswald